# Choice of VMWare Esxi host

Tags: vmware, esxi

Given a vsphere client, I am trying to find a way to determine the ESXi host on which a VM of provided specs can be spawned. Does anyone know of any formula by means of which one could relate the available CPU, ram and disk on an ESXi host and make a decision as to which host is a better choice to use to spawn a VM of a defined flavor - flavor here being a specified set of cpus, ram and disk.

Basically, I want to determine the number of VMs of a given specification (CPU, ram and disk) that can be spawned on a host.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Configuration Maximums](https://configmax.vmware.com/home) page to determine how many Esxi instances your physical hardware supports.

The upper limit is 128 virtual CPUs, 6 TB of RAM and 120 devices

Answer (score 0):

There's two main ways to go about this:

1. If you happen to have access to vROps, they have that capability
   built in the "Optimize Capacity" section of their UI.
2. Use your programming language of choice to perform those
   calculations manually. Referencing a single host, divide the host's
   available CPU MHz by the desired VM MHz, divide the host's available
   RAM by the desired VM RAM, take the host's datastore with the lowest
   about of space and divide that by the desired space of the VM. The
   lowest returned figure from those 3 calculations will be your max
   number of VMs that can be spawned on that particular host.